# Carriage return not being trimmed when piping to String.trim

Tags: string, elixir

I'm tinkering with learning Elixir coming from a Ruby background. I noticed that when I pipe the result of String.trim() to IO.puts() the string is printed with it's carriage return intact

```
token = IO.gets "enter your token" |> String.trim() |> IO.puts()
```

returns `"string123\n"`

However, if I do something like this:

```
token = IO.gets "enter your token" |> String.strip()
IO.puts(token)
```

The output is then `"string123"`

Why is my first solution not trimming the carriage return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** It’s a <del>race condition</del> precedence issue. What you get is the result of calling [`IO.gets/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#gets/2) that gets completed *the last*.

---

Actually, the first line does some weird assignment. [`IO.puts/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#puts/2) *returns `:ok` always*, it does not return a string, it spits it out to `stdout`. What happens, is (I put the order in which functions get executed):

```rb
#       6       1                  2  3             4  5
token = IO.gets "enter your token" |> String.trim() |> IO.puts()

# it’s the same as:
token = IO.gets("enter your token" |> String.trim() |> IO.puts())
```

One might put parentheses around the argument to [`IO.gets/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#gets/2), but this will only shift an issue to another part of code.

```rb
token = IO.gets("enter your token") |> String.trim() |> IO.puts()
#⇒ enter your token123
#  123
# :ok

token
#⇒ :ok
```

So far, `String.trim/1` works perfectly. What you need is to just assign the returned result to your `token` variable:

```rb
token = "enter your token" |> IO.gets() |> String.trim()
```

Now you get your trimmed value in your `token` variable.